# Why do hash keys have different order when printing?

Tags: perl, sorting, data-structures, hash, perl-data-structures

I want to build several hashes using the same keys and for the keys to have the same order when I print them. So, in the example below, the keys of `$hash1` and `$hash2` should always have the same order, but there should be no need to keep that order when creating the hash.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $hash1 = {
  keyc => 2,
  key1 => 1,
  keya => 3,
  keyb => 4,
};

my $hash2 = {
  keyc => 2,
  key1 => 1,
  keya => 3,
  keyb => 4,
};

print Dumper $hash1, $hash2;
```

But the output is as follows:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'key1' => 1,
          'keyc' => 2,
          'keyb' => 4,
          'keya' => 3
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'keyb' => 4,
          'keya' => 3,
          'keyc' => 2,
          'key1' => 1
        };
```

*i.e* the hashes have a different and unexpected order. What's wrong with my perl?

My perl version is:

```
This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Notice: I know that keys of perl hash is unsorted order. I want they have the same order, but there should be no need to have the sorted order. I hope that I can get the same print output if I run the code again.

Following advice from answers, I set two environment variables:

`PERL_HASH_SEED=0x00 PERL_PERTURB_KEYS=0`

Then I can get the same output when I run the code repeatedly.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Hashes are inherently not ordered.

Comment: You would set `PERL_HASH_SEED` and use `PERL_PERTURB_KEYS=0` If you want the keys to stay in their *insertion order*  (ordered but not sorted).  This was not clear in your question.  If you are serious about maintaining the order *in the application* (rather than relying on an environment variable) you would  be better off tieing the hash with one of the CPAN modules that were mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When printing a hash there are a few different notions of order that are relevant: "insertion order", "sort order" and "random". See the [ENVIRONMENT section of the `perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#ENVIRONMENT) documentation for a discussion of ways you can control this behavior and for the reasons why the default is to use hash randomization.

For at least a decade hashes in perl have not guaranteed key order.  More recently, hash randomization has been part of a general security "hardening" effort. There are good reasons for hashes to be randomized. For more details see the [`perlsec` discussion of algorithmic complexity attacks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks). You'll note in the Perl security documentation that further enhancements were added in `perl-5.18` - if you are seeing a different behavior compared to previous versions it may be due to these most recent changes.

Besides explicitly [sorting your hash keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) in a deterministic way, there are other approaches you can take to ordering your hashes: [`Hash::Ordered`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Ordered) is one example. The `Hash::Ordered` documentation has a good discussion of the pros and cons of a number of other modules.

While a hash is an "*unordered basket*" of scalars arranged in key-value pairs; an array *is* an "*ordered sequence*" of scalars <sup>[**1**]</sup>. A "[slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)" is way of accessing "several elements of a list, an array, or a hash simultaneously". A slice uses the `@` sigil since the operation returns a list of multiple values - and with `@` we get "ordered sequence". The upshot is that one way to impose a kind of "order" on a hash is by using a slice to access it:

```
# We want alphabetical disorder ...
my %hashed = ( 1 => "z", 2 => "x", 3 => "y" );
for my $key ( keys %hashed ) { print $hashed{$key} } ;
__END__    
zyx
```

We want "`zxy`" not "`zyx`". To impose our arbitrary version of order on this hash we first need to recognize that culprit here is `keys %hashed` which returns the keys in random order. The solution is to `sort` keys of ccurse and in this contrived example we store them in `@sort_order` and use it to "slice" out what we want from the hash, the way we want it:

```
my @sort_order = sort keys %hashed ;
print @hashed{@sort_order} ;
__END__
zxy
```

Tada!! Slices can be useful when you want to store keys and values in a hash but access that data in an ordered way. Remember the "`@`" when you want to slice a hash; as [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) puts it: "you use an `'@'` ... on a hash slice ... [because] you are getting back ...a list". And lists are orderly.

---

<sup>[**1**]</sup> The definitions of hashes as "unordered baskets" and arrays as "ordered sequence" are from Mike Friedman's (FRIEDO) excellent article on [Arrays vs. Lists in Perl](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl).

**Further References**

- *cf.* [`perlfaq` -q How can I always keep my hash sorted?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-always-keep-my-hash-sorted%3f)
- In addition to creating a number of really useful CPAN modules, GARU (Breno de Oliveira) published [an excellent article on hash ordering](http://onionstand.blogspot.ca/2012/12/are-you-relying-on-hash-keys-being.html) that thoroughly covers recent Perl development and hash randomization issues.
- For more advanced examples of neat things you can do with hash slices see Vince Veselosky's article [Hash slices can replace loops](http://www.webquills.net/web-development/perl/perl-5-hash-slices-can-replace.html).

Comment: I'd suggest adding a reference to hash slicing. E.g. `@hash{@element_order}` as I find that useful.

Comment: @Sobrique thanks ... I'm not sure if it is "idiomatic" but I sometimes store  ready-to-use arrays to use for slicing  ...

Comment: @lutaoact  - even more fun awaits with `perl-5.20` where you have the option to access a hash with `%hash{ @keys }` and get back a ready-made subset of the hash with [key/value slices](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/07/perl-5-20-introduces-keyvalue-slices/).

Comment: @mob thanks for edits on the `{` to `(` ... I dithered on whether to use a anonymous hash reference and  forgot to double check the `% ()` and `$ ()` ...

Answer (score 4):

Nothing wrong with your perl, a hash is unsorted.

If you want to sort by key you need to do something like that:

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %hash1) {
    print $key, $hash1{$key};
}
```

and same thing for hash2...

Comment: @mod Thanks for the edit yes just forgot the sort ! The most important part.

Answer (score 3):

G. Cito's answer is correct. If you want sorted output from Data::Dumper however, you can do:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $hash1 = {
  keyc => 2,
  key1 => 1,
  keya => 3,
  keyb => 4,
};

my $hash2 = {
  keyc => 2,
  key1 => 1,
  keya => 3,
  keyb => 4,
};

my $dumper = Data::Dumper->new([$hash1, $hash2]);
$dumper->Sortkeys(1);
print $dumper->Dump;
```

Comment: You can also set this as a variable to change the behavior of `print Dumper()` and friends. e.g. `$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1`;

Comment: I'd argue that if you're trying to sort it, then you don't want to be using `Dumper` in the first place.

Comment: Data::Dumper is fine for sorting. Use the `$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys` feature.